# Binding IsChecked property of Checkbox from Database in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, binding, datagrid

I´m trying to bind the property IsChecked of a checkbox when my datagrid gets loaded from database. 
In my database, i have this table that contains a column which receives a bit field.

So when the datagrid gets loaded, i have to verify if my column field is true or false. 
If it´s true, i want to set the IsChecked property of the checkbox to true.

I tried the code below but it didn´t work.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Classes:SetIsChecked x:Key="itemChecked" />

<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Name="ItemMarcado" Checked="ItemMarcado_Checked" 
          IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemChecked}, Path=Convert Mode=TwoWay,
           ConverterParameter=MARCADO, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }">
        </CheckBox>
     </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My C# code:

> class SetIsChecked : IValueConverter
>   {
>
> ```
>  public static bool IsChecked { get; set; }
>
>  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
>  {
>
>      Item item = (Item)value;
>      string tipoIcon = (string)parameter;
>
>         try
>         {                
>             if ((item.ItemMarcado == true) && (tipoIcon == "MARCADO"))
>             {
>                 IsChecked = true;
>                 return IsChecked;
>             }
>
>             IsChecked = false;
>             return IsChecked;
>         }
>         catch
>         {
>             IsChecked = false;
>             return IsChecked;
>         }
>     }
>
>     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
>     {
>         throw new NotImplementedException();
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That binding has so much wrong with it:

1. You are setting your source to a converter. Converters go in the "Converter" attribute.
2. You are setting the path to a function on the converter object. The path should be to the bit-field property.
3. You are using ConverterParameter correctly, but without the Converter property set, this isn't going to do a darn thing.
4. You have an update trigger of PropertyChanged on a checkbox, which never has/loses focus, so it will always change when the user clicks anyways! It won't hurt you, but you shouldn't need it.

That being said, your binding should just be:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=ItemMarcado}"
```

You could check against the "MARCADO" string with a converter, but with the binding you had it would always have that string anyways, so the additional complexity isn't worth it.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything or help in any other way!